# Nginx + Ubuntu + Gunicorn + ORACLE CLOUD Private/Public IP

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

Im deploying my website into OCI account. In my cloud I have 2 IP adresses: **Public and Private** and im not sure how to setup my webserver. Here bellow is my code:

**NGINX setup**

```
server {
        listen  0;
        server_name **PRIVATE IP**;

location /static/ {

        root /home/ubuntu/static/;

} 

location / {
        proxy_pass http:**PRIVATE IP**:8000;
}

}
```

**GUNICORN setup**

```
command = '/home/ubuntu/py_env/bin/gunicorn'                            
pythonpath = '/home/ubuntu/blog'
bind = '**PRIVATE IP**:8000'
workers = 3
```

Please advice how to setup it properly so i can access it from my browser via its IP.

Im trying to access my website with is located on cloud by my browser via its IP adress.

Answer (score 0):

i resolve this issue on my own. Let me share with you:

**Setup for Gunicorn:**

```
command = '/home/ubuntu/py_env/bin/gunicorn'
pythonpath = '/home/ubuntu/blog'
bind = '0.0.0.0:8000'
workers = 4
```

**Setup for Nginx**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name public_IP;

    location /static/ {
                   root /home/ubuntu/static/;
            }

    location / {
                       proxy_pass private_IP;
            }
}
```

Basically my problem was not caused by my setups. It was due my lack of VCN (Virtual Cloud Network) settings for port **80 (for http connections)** and **443 (for https connections)**. All was fine except that none connection could be established because of lack of those settings. For more details you can check this guy video (22.00) where he shows his setup and transfer it to your project:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1fjpNXK7yqc